# Nothing happens when trying to dial a number

Tags: ios-simulator

I'm trying to programmatically dial a phone number on iPhone by running this command:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:555-555-5555"]];
```

But, nothing happens, as if the command never ran.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the simulator allows you to place a phone call.

Comment: So, should I leave it this way and it will work properly on the device?